# I'm getting Subscript out of range (Error 9)

Tags: vba, excel

the below code is not working I'm getting Subscript out of range (Error 9)

```
Sub advnextract()

Sheets.Add(Before:=ActiveSheet).Name = "Resultado"

Set extractto = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Resultado").Range("A5:G5")


    Selection.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range( _
        "J1:J2"), CopyToRange:=extractto, Unique:=False

End Sub
```

Need help this is supposed to run a advanced filter and paste the result in the newly created sheet, the original table in the selection has data ranging from A1 to G11

Comment: When you add the new sheet it becomes active so your AF line is referring to the wrong sheet. You need to either re-activate the original sheet or, better, add sheet references.

Comment: I did notice that and chenged it to `Sub advnextract()

Sheets.Add(Before:=ActiveSheet).Name = "Resultado"

Set extractto = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Resultado").Range("A5:G5")

With Worksheets("Hoja1")
    
    Range("A1:G11").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range( _
        "J1:J2"), CopyToRange:=extractto, Unique:=False
End With
End Sub`

Still not working

Comment: Ouch, posting more than one line of code in the comments is hopeless I'm afraid.

Comment: Not a strict duplicate, but relying on `Active` or `Selection` is very error prone, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the creation of a worksheet causes that to gain focus.  Also you need to copy the titles to the sheet so excel knows where to put the values:

```
Sub advnextract()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim extractto as range

Set rng = Selection 'It is better to set an actual range instead of Selection.
                    'Also Selection must have at least 7 columns or this will error.
                    'It also needs to include the column headers in the Selection.
Sheets.Add(Before:=ActiveSheet).Name = "Resultado"

Set extractto = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Resultado").Range("A5:G5")
extractto.Value = rng.Rows(1).Value

    rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=ws.Range( _
        "J1:J2"), CopyToRange:=extractto, Unique:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: And of course you should also check if your "Resultado" sheet does not already exist.

Comment: Still geting the error 9 in this line

`Set extractto = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Resultado").Range("A5:G5")`

Comment: Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer. @TomRuiz

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error and some insight into some logic here is the final result

```
Sub advnextract()
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Selection
Sheets.Add(Before:=Sheets("Hoja1")).Name = "Resultado"


   rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Hoja1").Range("J1:J2"), _
   CopyToRange:=Sheets("Resultado").Range("A1"), Unique:=False

   Sheets("Resultado").Activate
   Columns("A:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit
   Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

I know it can be improved to be more efficient but for some reason I can't  explain this is the code that works for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros